# Trying to change my SQLLITE line by line insert query to bulk insert in python, how I can achieve it

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have this code to insert line by line from CSV file. it is working fine for a small CSV file. However now I have a CSV file with 15 million records. How I can change it to bulk insert. Really appreciate your help.

```
with open(goodFilePath+'/'+file, "r") as f:
                    next(f)
                    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\n")
                    for line in enumerate(reader):
                        for list_ in (line[1]):
                            try:
                                conn.execute('INSERT INTO Good_Raw_Data values ({values})'.format(values=(list_)))
                                self.logger.log(log_file," %s: File loaded successfully!!" % file)
                                conn.commit()
                            except Exception as e:
                                raise e
```

Comment: Please format your code above. See how it is just one big jumble? If it is separated on different lines in your editor, highlight it all and hit ctrl-k (or command-k on a mac) to format as code.

Comment: I formatted the code, hope it helps

Comment: Better - you should be able to see a preview as you edit it. See how all the lines after the 1st are indented like 30 spaces? You can maybe just indent them 4 spaces from the 1st line, etc. But it is readable now.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using sqlite's `executemany`, intended for bulk inserts. It wasn't clear to me how many different values you are inserting, but here's an example if there are two columns:

```
conn.executemany(
    'INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (?,?)',
    [
        (1, 'value1'),    # Insert 1 in the first column, and 'value1' in the 2nd col
        (2, 'value2'),
        (3, 'another_value')
    ]
)
```

In other words, you'll want to create either a generator function, or just a list, whose elements are n-tuples where n is the number of values to insert in each row.

Hope this helps, happy coding!

Comment: there are 8 different values.

Comment: Ok, then you want an 8-tuple, or a list with 8 elements for the insert!